# How to write if statement that verify attribute and class

Tags: javascript, cypress

my test has to click on the specific main tab that expands the bar with other tabs. If you click on any tab, the tab will be active, and second click on active tab redirect you to the different page. Second tab on the bar is active by default so If you click on this active tab the site redirect you to the different page (I dont want that). So when bar with tabs will pop up I want to verify which tab is active and then decide to clikc on proper tab and run the function or if proper tab is selected by default I just want to run function.

Main tab open bar:

1. tab_1:
   class="same" |
   attribute="tab_1"
2. tab_2:
   class="same **active**" <- marked by default) |
   attribute="tab_2"
3. tab_3
   class="same" |
   attribute="tab_3"

It would be like 20 tabs in different order and I want to verify only 5 of them, so the second tab on the bar might be called for instance "bmw" and in next time "subaru" instead of "bmw".

'

```
cy.get('main_tab').click()

// only attribute makes each element unique. If element is active class="same active"    
if (active_element contain attribute="tab_2") {
    run function 
} else {
    cy.get(tab_2).click()
    run function
}
```

Do you have any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
cy.get('tab-selector').each(($ele) => {
  if($ele.hasClass('same active') && $ele.attr("tab_2")){
    //Do Something
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Select your active tab and check attribute with `.attr()`

```js
cy.get('main_tab').click()

cy.get('.active').then($activeTab => {

  if ($activeTab.attr('tab_2').length > 0) {
    run function 
  } else {
    cy.get(tab_2).click()
    run function
}
```